# Getting comments of an specefic user

Tags: comments

i am using this code:

```
$args = array(
    'user_id' => get_current_user_id(),
    );
$comment = get_comments( $args ); 

var_dump($comment);
wp_list_comments("callback=wpsaz_comment&end-callback=dubfa_div&per_page=5",$comment);
```

i dont know what is wrong with it.

user is logged in but the array is empty. 
whats wrong 
?

[image: Comments]

[image: Query]

Comment: fixed! i was using ajax to insert comments. forgot to add 'user_id' for wp_insert_comment function.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this way:

```
<?php
$my_user = get_current_user_id();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom-post-type',
    'user_id' => $my_user,

);
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
endforeach;

?>
```

Provided that your user has comments!!

Comment: thanks. but that is not working either. the returned $comments is empty!

Comment: i am using this code in a page with custom page template if this helps.

Comment: without more details on the page, I cannot see other problems than catching the user_id before the args array.

Comment: and also i am sure that the user passed to get_comments has two comments in custom_post_type.

Comment: Ahh, you didn't say that it was a CPT. I have edited my code.

Comment: did not work either. i added some pictures see the question.

Comment: I suppose you replaced 'custom-post-type' with your current post type string, didn't you?

Comment: $args = array(
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id(),
  'post_type' => 'movies',
  );

Comment: the code is correct. Try enabling WP_DEBUG and look if any warning pops up. Otherwise try using it on a standard page, not the custom template, to isolate the problem.

Comment: already enabled debug, but no error related to this code pops up. i am now using it on another page to see if it works. by the way this code is on another .php file which i am using the code get_template_part to show it. would this affect?

Comment: it should not affect. Another troubleshooting action could be to replace get_current_user() and manually insert a valid ID of an user with comments.

Comment: tried that but nothing. another thing that might affect is i am using ajax to add comments and the function i am using is wp_insert_comment

Comment: well i found the issue. i did not use 'user_id' parameter to specify which user is this comment for wp_insert_comment.